# How can I upgrade Eclipse Luna to Mars from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I tried upgrading from Luna to Mars by following the instructions here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F

I added the Mars repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars as an update site and then did check for updates. But I get the exception

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.java,4.5.0.20150603-1639
No repository found containing: binary,epp.package.java.executable.gtk.linux.x86_64,4.5.0.20150603-1639
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature,4.5.0.20150603-1639
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature,4.5.0.20150603-1639
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't.  Unpack Eclipse Mars to a different directory and use a different work space for your Mars projects.  Carefully, one project at a time, copy your projects from the Luna work space to the Mars work space.  That way, you can fall back to Luna when you have problems with Mars.

Comment: Try again a little later. Not all the repositories went up on time.

Comment: It works now, but cannot start Eclipse, since JVM 7 is required.

Comment: You should probably install the latest JDK then ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Done that. Might be something Eclipse should mention, though, that this upgrade needs to happen in order to work with Mars.

Comment: Well, Java 7 was released in 2011, over 4 years ago. We're on 8 now.

Comment: How is that relevant?

Comment: Make a copy/backup of your eclipse and workspace folders. That way you have a way to fall back if anything brakes.

Answer (score 4):

Before upgrading I first check the availables web sites for update. I disable all from the previous releases and start by performing an update on the already installed components. After this upgrade I just add

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

and upgrade to the new release of eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea. If you upgrade your Eclipse, it will be difficult to fall back when you want to (and you will).

Better is to create a new Eclipse instance and new (set of) workspace(s) for Mars. Then either point to your existing Team repositories or import your existing projects.

Comment: You can use the rollback function from within Eclipse

Comment: This is a "How do I..." question, not an "Is it a good idea to..." question.

Comment: There are no "Is it a good idea to..." questions. Such a thing would be flagged as opinion-based.

Comment: and +1 for the "and you will", it is a flawless affirmation :)

Comment: I upgraded eclipse Luna to Mars by just adding http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars to my available sites and then triggering an update. Everything went well and I am using Mars smoothly without any issues

Comment: I can totally relate to the desire to upgrade: export/import of prefs does not cover all settings and uninstalled plug-ins leave loads of data behind. Therefore, starting from a new workspace is a pain as so many settings have to be reconfigured manually: label decorations, colors and fonts, file editors & content types, validations, type filters, you name it... I just moved to Neon (new instance and new workspace): over 4 hours and I'm not even sure I've touched all settings I've configured over the years. Hopefully, Oomph and saving to the cloud will make the next migration easier.

Comment: Yay Oomph! :-) It's my favorite underutilized feature. @AbVog

Comment: @roneo (or anyone), do you have any idea whether your trick will update Luna directly to Neon? Or is an in-between update to Mars a better idea?

Comment: @Steve, in between upgrade is always a better idea but you can try to jump version and check for yourself. I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know how relevant it is but for the record I not only added the mars release update site but also this one: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5

Maybe a duplicate? If so, let me know ;)